# SQL Server 2012 - frequent "System Health Monitor Thread: Operating system error Exception 0x1 encountered"

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012

In Windows Server 2012 We have installed SQL Server 2012 Standard edition last few months we are getting  this error in event viewer "System Health Monitor Thread: Operating system error Exception 0x1 encountered". And also SQL Server have Timeout error.

**Action I Took:**

1. Deleted Unused Databases
2. Shrink Log file

But Still getting Time out error and Operating System Error exception.

Comment: Did you install SP3 (the latest service pack)? If not, please install. A similar problem was fixed at one of the hotfixes released after SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using 32 bit version of SQL server,then you can apply SP4 to resolve the issue or try patching to latest [version](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/team-posts/latest-builds-sql-server-2012/)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2828833